# Explain this HAML and Ruby weird code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to HAML and Ruby but I am trying to change some standard buttons on a form that I have into radio buttons.  The code works.  I just need to learn how to change it.  I have absolutely no idea what this line of HAML code means other than I know it outputs my two buttons.  The code is this:

```
      = render @audience, opportunity: :opportunity
```

The output in the browser looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default audience-tab active" data-value="consumer" data-remote="true" href="/opportunities/229/edit?audience=consumer">Consumer</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default audience-tab " data-value="business" data-remote="true" href="/opportunities/229/edit?audience=business">Business</a>
</div>
```

I know I have a table in my database called `Opportunities`.  It contains a field called `audience`.  The few relevant lines in my controller look like this:

```
    @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:id])
```

Then I have this in my controller also.

```
    if params[:audience].present?
      @audience = params[:audience]
    else
      @audience = @opportunity.audience || 'consumer'
    end
```

What I really want to know is what the heck this HAML stuff means.

```
= render @audience, opportunity: :opportunity
```

Especially `opportunity: :opportunity`.  What do the colons mean?  Why the redundancy?  If I can figure that out then I can probably understand how I need to change it to meet my needs.

Comment: In ruby, you can have a hash where both `key` and `value` can be `symbols`. So, `opportunity: :opportunity` is essentially the same as `:opportunity => :opportunity`, In this case, you're passing `local variables` to the `_audience.html.haml` partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render` is not haml is a rails method

```
= render @audience, opportunity: :opportunity
```

you probably have string html/haml in this variable `@audience`

`render @audience`is rendering what is on @audience and `opportunity: :opportunity` pass the value `:opportunity` in variable `opportunity` with `locals render`options

Please watch this video to learn how to debug your code [RailsCast Pry debug](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails)